# Why my static files are not getting loaded?

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

i am building real estate web app. My static files are not getting loaded.

I have done all the possible settings to laod my static files in my app but it doesn't work. Below is my code, could any one help me to get rid of this.

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Marwat Real Estate</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/all.css' %}">
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}">
<!-- Custom -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
<!-- light box -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/lightbox.min.css' %}">



STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'btre/static')
]
```

Comment: make sure your `urls.py` has `urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)`

Comment: I paste this code in my urls.py but not working.. how to config this settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Follow this steps:

1. Make a folder named **static** in the app(where you are working in)
2. Make the **style.css** inside the **static** folder
3. Make a folder named **templates** in the project folder.
4. Add a html file inside the **templates** folder.
5. Register the **templates**  folder in the settings.py.
   eg:

   ```
     TEMPLATES = [
   {
       'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
       'DIRS': [
           'templates'
           ],
       'APP_DIRS': True,
       'OPTIONS': {
           'context_processors': [
               'django.template.context_processors.debug',
               'django.template.context_processors.request',
               'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
               'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
           ],
       },
   },
   ]
   ```
6. Add the static files inside the html file as given below:
   eg:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "style.css" %}" />
```

Happy Djangoing... :)

Comment: its not working joju, could you suggest me another way to sort this out

Comment: Did you follow the same steps?.